# Add objects to a list from a text file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here is my code: it only adds the first 1(Roberto) from the .txt
the text contains:

1,2343443,Roberto,Lopez

2,3434343,Jose,Perez

3,12123242,Dario,Gimenez

0,45789432,jorge,Lopez

```
[HttpPost]
public string CargarAlumnos()
{
    List<Alumno> lstAlumnos = new List<Alumno>();
    if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        var file = Request.Files[0];

        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file.InputStream);
            do
            {
                string textLine = reader.ReadLine();
                textLine.Replace("<br>", "");
                String[] dato = textLine.Split(',');
                while (textLine != null)
                {
                        Alumno nAlu = new Alumno
                        {
                            numero = Convert.ToInt32(dato[0]),
                            cedula = dato[1],
                            nombre = dato[2],
                            apellido = dato[3]
                        };
                        lstAlumnos.Add(nAlu);
                    textLine = reader.ReadLine();
                }reader.Close();
            }while (reader.Peek() != -1);

            return "Alumnos Cargados";
        }
    }

    return "No se pudo procesar el archivo";
}
```

Comment: What is your actual .txt file content?

Comment: this 1,2343443,Roberto,Lopez

2,3434343,Jose,Perez

3,12123242,Dario,Gimenez

0,45789432,jorge,Lopez

Comment: Is on the top of the question, and only adds the first line

Comment: Your logic is bit complex to understand. This is the simple code to read text file. `StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file.InputStream);

            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                line = line.Replace("<br>", "");
                string[] data = line.Split(',');

                if (data != null && data.Count() > 0)
                {
                    // YOUR DATA IS HERE
                }
            }`

Comment: thx, im gonna try that

Comment: There is no need for two loops. Put your comments whether it worked or not.

Comment: System.FormatException "Input string was not in a correct format."  after adding 1 Alumno

Comment: Is it a csv file? Why not use CsvHelper?

Comment: No, is a text file(.txt)

Comment: Try like `string result = new StreamReader(file.InputStream).ReadToEnd();`. And check what value you get on `result`.

Comment: 1,2343443,Roberto,Lopez\r\n\r\n2,3434343,Jose,Perez\r\n\r\n3,12123242,Dario,Gimenez\r\n\r\n0,45789432,jorge,Lopez\r\n\r\n" dats the value of result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You took loops and that is making logic complex unnecessarily. Following code is very simple to read a text file. Tested and working.

```
[HttpPost]
public string CargarAlumnos()
{
    List<Alumno> lstAlumnos = new List<Alumno>();
    if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        var file = Request.Files[0];

        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file.InputStream);

            while (!reader.EndOfStream) 
            { 
                var line = reader.ReadLine(); 
                line = line.Replace("<br>", ""); 
                string[] data = line.Split(','); 

                if (data != null && data.Count() > 0) 
                { 
                    // YOUR DATA IS HERE 
                    Alumno nAlu = new Alumno
                    {
                        numero = Convert.ToInt32(data[0]),
                        cedula = data[1],
                        nombre = data[2],
                        apellido = data[3]
                    };

                    lstAlumnos.Add(nAlu);
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the same errorSystem.FormatException "Input string was not in a correct format." after adding 1 Alumno

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(dato[0]),` check this line. I think some data is having alphanumeric value.

Comment: lstAlumnos.Add(nAlu);

Comment: put the definition of `Alumno` class in question.

Comment: public class Alumno
    {
        [Key]
        public int numero{get;set;}
        public string cedula { get; set; }
        public string nombre { get; set; }
        public string apellido { get; set; }
    }

Comment: I tested this code with your class and it is working without any error. Some possibilities for errors are  1. Some data in your text file is not in proper format so it causes error at `Convert.ToInt32(dato[0])`  this line.   2. Your database table structure is different than you defined in class. Check all varchar or nvachar length in database.

Comment: With if (line != "") before the data worked. ty very much Dave